# How To Enable the WiFi Information Entitlement

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I'm making a react-native application for a DVR device, and updates happen via wifi, I need to get information about this connection, specifically ssid, I tried using react-native-wifi-reborn, but I can't get it, in the description of the library it is written that it is necessary to grant rights to wifi through capabilities, but there is no such thing, and every time I get an error that the ssid was not received, I will be grateful for any information, thanks

used the library and its methods, but it doesn't help

Comment: I forgot to clarify, I need information on iOS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code, that's the problem, I need to get information about the wi-fi connection, namely wi-fi

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that I used the simulator, and I could get data about wi-fi only after I add it to the apple store connection, there, when adding App ID, it indicated that I needed access to Wi-Fi, that's the only way I got access to it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).